# Validating user input excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following user input set up in excel vba. The function when called asks the user to input a single number no greater than 9999, or two numbers in the format XXXX-XXXX where two numbers are separated by a dash. In that case, the numbers cannot be greater than 9999 in either case, or at least shouldn't.

The goal is to return either a single number (IE 50) or a range (IE low value is 50,high value is 75). Currently as set up it should be returning an array, where the first position is the low value, and the second position is high value. Or, if the user only enters one number, it should return that one number in the first position of an array.

Currently it checks that A) user has entered in a number, B) the number is not greater than 4 digits long.

Unfortunately it is not returning an array, it is returning an error. Subscript out of range.

Also, are there any other likely user inputs that should be checked for here? The application is not going to be widely used by people, but I'd like to minimize potential errors as well.

```
Public Function getUserInput() As Variant
'this function gets a user input from an input box and puts it out into the proper format


        Dim inputString As String
        Dim numArr() As String

        Dim i As Long

      '  On Error GoTo NotValidInput
        inputString = Trim(InputBox("Enter the rows you'd like to print"))

      'has the user entered a dash into their user input

         If InStr(inputString, "-") > 0 Then
                numArr() = Split(inputString, "-")

                If UBound(numArr) <> 1 Then
                    GoTo NotValidNumberFormat
                End If
                If (IsNumeric(numArr(0)) And Len(numArr(0)) <= 4) And (IsNumeric(numArr(1)) And Len(numArr(1)) <= 4) Then

                    getUserInput = numArr
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    GoTo NotValidNumberFormat
                End If
        'no dash
        '60

         Else
            If (IsNumeric(CInt(inputString))) And Len(inputString) <= 4 Then
                    getUserInput = numArr
                Exit Function
            Else
                GoTo NotValidNumberFormat
            End If
         End If


Exit Function

NotValidNumberFormat:
'if the conversion failed, return error
MsgBox ("Please enter the number in a valid format - either a single number no larger than 9999 or two numbers no larger than 9999 separated by only one dash (IE XX-XX)")

getUserInput = -1

End Function
```

Comment: *Unfortunately it is not returning an array, it is returning an error. Subscript out of range* - Which line returns the error? Or, maybe more to the point, when you call this function from another sub are you assigning the result to a variant object type as well?

Comment: If you declare an array with open brackets, at some point you have to dimension it in your code. The alternative is to declare `Dim numArr As Variant`. If there is no dash in the response you are not assigning a value to numArr anywhere. That said, I can't see what your code is actually achieving.

Comment: What if the user input needs to be `-1`? How do you tell a valid `-1` from the `-1` "error value"? Use structured error handling instead of magic return values, and avoid `GoTo`.

Comment: Your solution isn't half as "generic" as it claims to be. Why not make a custom UserForm and *actually* validate user input as it happens, using customizeable validation rules, instead of prompting with an `InputBox` and then verifying and prompting again?

Comment: @Mat'sMug thanks; going to begin researching how to implement the userform tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

this should do:

```
Public Function getUserInput() As Variant
    'this function gets a user input from an input box and puts it out into the proper format
    Dim numArr As Variant
    Dim goOn As Boolean

    Do
        numArr = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(InputBox("Enter the rows you'd like to print in the format 'nnnn' or 'nnnn-mmmm'")), "-")
        Select Case UBound(numArr)
            Case 0
                goOn = Format(numArr(0), "0000") Like "####"
            Case 1
                goOn = Format(numArr(0), "0000") Like "####" And Format(numArr(1), "0000") Like "####"
        End Select
        If Not goOn Then MsgBox "Please enter the number in a valid format - either a single number no larger than 9999 or two numbers no larger than 9999 separated by only one dash (ex: XX-XX)"        
    Loop While Not goOn
    getUserInput = numArr
End Function
```